# Whenever I try to set an array of strings to another value, it doesnt change

Tags: java

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String question = in.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        answers[i] =  in.nextLine();
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        explanations[k] = in.nextLine();                    
        if (k == 3) {
            questions.add(new Question(question, answers, explanations));
            answers = null;
            explanations = null;
        }
    }
}
```

After the first runthrough, the answers and explanations arrays are just set to null and don't ever change, is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Please include the code as text into the question.

Comment: it has been edited

Comment: You need to create a new answers String array within the loop

Comment: holy... thank you so much Ive been working on this for like the past 3 hours....

Answer (score 0):

You are setting answers and explanations arrays to null inside the for loop, instead create new String arrays as below(just enter the correct size)

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
String question = in.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    answers[i] =  in.nextLine();
}
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
    explanations[k] = in.nextLine();                    
    if (k == 3) {
        questions.add(new Question(question, answers, explanations));
        answers = new String[100]; //Enter the correct size of the array
        explanations = new String[100]; //Enter the correct size of the array
        }
    }
}
```